# keep token updated on axios action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to consume an Express REST API that requires a valid json web token for some routes. Due to the fact I have to pass the token from the localstorage everytime I wanted to create an "Axios config file".

My file **http.js** contains the following code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

const devInstance = createInstance("http://localhost:3000");

devInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    console.log(config);
    return config;
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
});

devInstance.interceptors.response.use(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
});

const productionInstance = createInstance("http://www.myApi.com");

function createInstance(baseURL){
    return axios.create({
        baseURL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
        }
    });
}

Vue.prototype.$http = devInstance; // Check debug/build mode
```

within my **main.js** I import this instance once

```
import http from "./http.js";
```

and from now on I can use `this.$http` to get the global axios instance without importing it.

When consuming the API `localStorage.token` returns undefined because it is not set when creating the instance.

How can I keep this `Authorization` attribute updated without passing in the token manually each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should write a request interceptor that adds the `Authorization` header to all requests.

```
devInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`;
    return config;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));
```

This way you will always get the currently stored token.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a timer and an async update for that Authorization field. Either a separate component that handles that, or a timer and async method on that component (not sure if you can do this with Vue though).

Hope it helps.
Cheers